# It's not going to controller function that i given in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I am trying to delete an item and that is passed to controller using ajax and jquery. But when i click the button(I gave the function in onclick) it alerts the value I alerted. but not going to the controller function

I have tried almost everything I know. but not working

```
var parameter = {
  transaction_id: transaction_id,
  date: date,
  bank_transfer_amount: bank_transfer_amount,
  reference_number: reference_number,
  transfer_id: transfer_id
};

alert(transaction_id);

$.ajax({
  url: get_base_url() + 'delete_cash_to_bank_transfer_details',
  data: parameter,
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    if (data.status) {
      window.location.replace('bank_to_cash_edit_list');
    }
  }
});
```

Expected result is go to controller and delete data.

But it's not even going to controller.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I made a small mistake that when getting values from view,

It was like

```
var date = $('#date');
```

Instead of

```
var date = $('#date').val();
```

I added that `val()` and worked fine